# Disable Csrf for ajax query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and i'm tryin to disable csrf validation for this route to be able to perform some remote validations using [Jquery Form Validator](http://www.formvalidator.net/#security-validators_backend) :

```
Route::post('verify', 'formController@check');
```

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection), I just have to add my URI to the `$exclude`property. whice I did :

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
/**
 * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $except = [
    'verify',
];
}
```

That did not work, So I tried to disable csrf validation for the whole application :

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
protected $middleware = [
    ...
    //\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
];
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
];
}
```

That did not work either. I keep getting this error on the console :

> POST http://domain.name/verify 500 (Internal Server Error)

whice exactly points to this line(The validator's js file):

> ajax({url:b,type:"POST",cache:!1,data:g,dataType:"json",error:function(a){return h({valid:!1,message:"Connection failed with status: "+a.statusText},f),!1}

What am I missing? thanks for your help.

Comment: If you have disabled CSRF for the whole application and that route still doesn't work, then your problem is not CSRF. You either have an issue with your route or the way you are calling it.

Comment: If you had the "CSRF" problem you should have the CSRF error, so, as Andy has said, there must be another problem.

Comment: Check your server error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem.

For Laravel 5 and above, adding `protected $except = ['verify',];` to `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php` does solve the problem.

NB : Google's inspect tool (Network menu) helped me understand what was really happening.

Answer (score 1):

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{

```
protected $except_urls = [
    'verify'
];

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $regex = '#' . implode('|', $this->except_urls) . '#';

    if ($this->isReading($request) || $this->tokensMatch($request) || preg_match($regex, $request->path()))
    {
        return $this->addCookieToResponse($request, $next($request));
    }

    throw new TokenMismatchException;
}
```

}